# Get/split text inside brackets/parentheses

Tags: regex, vb.net

Just have a list of words, such as:

```
gram (g)
kilogram (kg)
pound (lb)
```

just wondering how I would get the words within the brackets for example get the "g" in "gram (g)" and dim it as a new string.
Possibly using regex?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use split function ..

```
strArr  = str.Split("(")  ' splitting 'gram (g)' returns an array ["gram " , "g)"] index 0 and 1
strArr2 = strArr[1].Split(")") ' splitting 'g)' returns an array ["g " ..]
```

the string is in

```
strArr2[0]
```

**Edit**

you want getAbbrev and getAbbrev2 to be arrays

try

```
Dim getAbbrev As String() = Str.Split("(") 
Dim getAbbrev2 as String() = getAbbrev[1].Split(")")
```

To do it without declaring arrays you can do

```
"gram (g)".Split("(")[1].Split(")")[0]
```

but that's unreadable

**Edit**

You have some very trivial errors. I would suggest you strengthen your understanding on objects and declarations first. Then you can look into invoking methods. I rather have you understand it than give it to you. Re-read the book you have or look for a basic tutorial.

```
Dim unit As String = 'make sure this is the actual string you are getting, not sure where you are supposed to get the string value from => ie grams (g)

Dim getAbbrev As String() = unit.Split("(") 'use unit not Str - Str does not exist
Dim getAbbrev2 As String() = getAbbrev[1].Split(")") 'As no as - case sensitive
```

for the last line reference `getAbbrev2` instead of the unknown `abbrev2`

Comment: Just keep getting identifier expected inside the brackets such as "[1]" etc. Any idea on a fix? [http://i.imgur.com/SzX0m.png](http://i.imgur.com/SzX0m.png)

That's what I have at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Fun with Regular Expressions  (I'm really not an expert here, but tested and works)

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
.....

Dim charsToTrim() As Char = { "("c, ")"c }
Dim test as String = "gram (g)" + Environment.NewLine +   
         "kilogram (kg)" + Environment.NewLine +   
         "pound (lb)"  

Dim pattern as String = "\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\)"
Dim r As Regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Dim m As Match = r.Match(test)
While(m.Success)
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Match" + "=" + m.Value.ToString())
   Dim tempText as String = m.Value.ToString().Trim(charsToTrim)
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("String Trimmed" + "=" + tempText)
   m = m.NextMatch()
End While
```

Comment: Instead of the class `[a-zA-Z0-9]` it's easier to use the character class of "anything that's not a right parenthesis" : `[^)]`. This is shorter and also allows symbols like `$` to appear in the parenthesis (`Dollars ($)`).

Comment: @Li-aungYip thanks, As said, I'm not an expert here. I just tried something that I remembered from the days when to write code I had only a simple text editor. :)

Comment: Well hey, your version works fine - my suggestion was just polishing. ;)

Comment: Also: TEXT EDITORS? Back in my day we had a stack of cards and a one-hole punch...

Answer (score 0):

You can split at the space and remove the parens from the second token (by replacing them with an empty string).

A regex is also an option, and is very simple, its pattern is

`\w+\s+\((\w+)\)`

Which means, a word, then at least one space, then opening parens, then in real regex parens you search for a word, and, eventually a closing paren. The inner parentheses are capturing parentheses, which make it possible to refer to the unit g, kg, lb.